# mysql join with varchar fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I need to join 2 tables

a) table_a

```
id        ref_no                        name
---------------------------------------------------
1       HRTU/00000001/2013             ram
2       HRTU/00000002/2013             sam
```

b) table_b

```
       ref_no                        desg
---------------------------------------------------
    HRTU/00000001/2013               project manager
    HRTU/00000002/2013               developer
```

these 2 tables will be joined by their ref_no. and will give me output like below

c) output_table

```
 ref_no                              name                             desg
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    HRTU/00000001/2013               ram                       project manager
    HRTU/00000002/2013               sam                         developer
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Too trivial if you know what joins are.

Comment: You must ask specific questions and  present what you have done on stack overflow.

Comment: @SalmanA yes I know. please try it by yourself and give me the query which gives 100% correct result of my requirement. thanks.

Comment: How about you 100% try first, and show what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*  -- SELECT columns you want
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.ref_no = b.ref_no
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08d91/1)

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: it will not work. I've tried it. will return more than 2 results. :(

Comment: @ripa then why is it working on the fiddle? check the link `:D`

Comment: @ripa  The table design is problematic since you have long strings  " ref_no"  to join together. You should join using the foreign key / primary key as integer to join

Comment: @RajuGujarati yes it may be db design problem. But it is the requirement of the project.

Comment: @ripa can you show the results? how about adding *DISTINCT*, eg `SELECT DISTINCT a.*, ....`

Comment: @JW. DISTINCT will return single record. but I need multiple record depending on multiple ref_no

Comment: can you show it along with your example?

Comment: @JW. I have edited my question. please look at it and please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.ref_no AS ref_no, a.valp AS name, b.desg AS desg
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.ref_no = b.ref_no
```

With "AS" in SELECT you can give the columns names

Comment: sorry man. doesn't fulfill my requirement :(